# "OpenGL project" template in Code Blocks crashes the graphics driver when the "Minimize" button is clicked

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I am developing a OpenGL/C++ game for Windows and using Code::Blocks as an IDE. I created a project from the OpenGL template in Code::Blocks to get the setting up of OpenGL right, but there is a very annoying side effect.

When I click Minimize button, I either get a screen freeze and then an error message that tells me that the graphics driver has stopped working, or a screen of death.

Is there a good fix for that (the bug is not caused by something I have done to the code, I get the same one from the template alone)?

If it is caused by my hardware, I guess I'll have to change the default behaviour of the button or even just disable it. If you need samples of code from the event handling or the setting up of OpenGL, please ask and I will edit the post.

Comment: Looks like some problems with OpenGL driver. What OS do you use? Is everything updated?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in the code.

Comment: @AlexFarber No, the problem is either PEBKAC or a bug in the code.

Comment: @BЈовић - AFAIK, OpenGL code should not cause BSOD, even if the code is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexFarber I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit, my graphics card is a AMD Radeon HD 6650 M. The driver appears to be up to date.

Comment: I know that minimizing a window tends to screw with resize events if it isn't handled right.  Maybe post your resize code?

Comment: [Looks like you are not alone](http://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=AMD+Radeon+HD+6650+M+problem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk&redir_esc=&ei=UDdEUN7FFJDJsgakoYCIDg#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=rtP&channel=fs&gl=uk&biw=1081&bih=658&sclient=psy-ab&q=AMD+Radeon+HD+6650+M+driver+causing+BSOD&oq=AMD+Radeon+HD+6650+M+driver+causing+BSOD&gs_l=serp.3...2762.10557.0.10932.27.25.2.0.0.0.507.4350.1j20j0j3j0j1.25.0...1.0...1c.v4wHRZrlZ6U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=6d39b47604216962)

Comment: I tested my game on friends computers and it worked perfectly. I guess that means that the driver is actually responsible.